# How to open "Contact" and select a number

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a input field which will open "Contact" or "Phonebook" and let the user to choose a contract number from there. I couldn't find any html input type to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to access your phone with plain html/css/js. If you want functionality to access Contacts, Camera, GPS and so on, you could create a hybrid app with Cordova. Then you can use the many plugins that make your dreams come true.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. The way to do this is using the Contact Picker API. This is available from chrome 80, and also now available in iOS advanced browser setting.

Check the following resources;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Contact_Picker_API